# Return false statement not working for my form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and i am validating it by checking if there is no empty field left by putting an alert and returning false so that it remains on the same page and doesn't go to the next page. Although i am getting the alert but still it proceeds to next page.

```js
function fnOnSubmit() {
  $('#dataTable input,select').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == '' || val == 'undefined') {
      alert('Please fill all the fields');
      return false;
    }
  });
  var flag = '';
  $('#dataTable input:not([type=button]),#dataTable select').each(function () {
    flag = flag + (this.value) + '~';
    quicklink = flag;
  });
  document.frmmain.quicklink.value = quicklink;

  SendTxnRequest('02','QWC'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="id0">
      <td>
        <div class="id_100">
          <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField(this)">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <xsl:for-each select="faml/response/qlwidgetresponsedto/searchby/datamapdto">
              <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description" />
              <option value="#{description}">
                <xsl:value-of select="description" />
              </option>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="45" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="55" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="40" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton" type="button" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're returning from the `each()` handler. I'm not sure what you're expecting it to do, but I can tell you that it won't do anything at all. Are you trying to run this code under an event?

Comment: How/where are you calling `$('#dataTable input,select').each` - you probably need to `return false` from *that* not the inner anonymous function.

Comment: @Rory Yes when the initiate button is hit it will call a function under which my code is written for validation

Comment: In that case can you please add all relevant code to the question

Comment: I have update the code for you.